# Display log before results in SAS

Tags: sas

After submitting code to SAS, especially during development work, it is almost always necessary to check the log for errors etc before checking the results. Is there a way to have SAS default to displaying the log "on top" instead of the results viewer?

I'm using SAS-9, windowing environment.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, but if you go to communities.sas.com you can add it as an idea and people can vote on it. Popular items get consideration and SAS/SAS developers monitor the forums there.

Comment: What did you set for the AUTOPOP window settings in the LOG and OUTPUT windows?  Are you using ODS output like HTML? or just the text based listing output (OUTPUT Window)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the default behavior of the F3, F8 etc keys by typing F9 key.

You can find this :
F3 : end;/* gsubmit buffer=default */

just add log after end; to have this: 
F3 : end; log /* gsubmit buffer=default */